# Parse Cloud Code httprequest error

Tags: javascript, http, parse-platform

I've been programming in Objective-C for years, but I need to work with Parse Cloud Code and I'm new to Javascript.

Here's my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://api-ilv.trulioo.com/partner/v3/truDetect',
    params: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'api_key':'1234567890',
        'provider_name':'fb',
        'provider_url':'https://www.facebook.com/testing'
    }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse.text);
    response.success(httpResponse.text);
}, 
function (httpResponse, error) {
    console.error('Request failed with response: ' + httpResponse.text);
    response.error('Request failed with response: ' + httpResponse.text)
});
});
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Made some changes to log in the code above. Here's the response:

```
{"code":141,"error":"Request failed with response: 405: Method Not Allowed"}
```

So now, it looks like the method is returning the error correctly. However, what does error code 405 mean?

Comment: "Request failed with response: 405: Method Not Allowed" is an HTTP error message telling you that you used `GET` requests, but the server expected `POST` (or vice versa, or a different request method). Consult the documentation of the HTTP API you are trying to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was POST. Needed to change it to POST

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {

    var baseurl = "https://api-ilv.trulioo.com/partner/v3/truDetect";

    var params = {
      'api_key':'1234567890',
      'provider_name':'fb',
      'provider_url':'https://www.facebook.com/testing'
    }

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: baseurl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
      body: params
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        response.success(httpResponse.text);
    }, 
    function (error) {
        console.error('Console Log response: ' + error.text);
        response.error('Request failed with response ' + error.text)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `then` part of the `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` expects two functions - the first one in for the success case and the second one for the error case.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://api-ilv.trulioo.com/v3/truDetect',
        params: {
            'api_key':'1234567890',
            'provider_name':'fb',
            'provider_url':'https://www.facebook.com/testing'
        }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        response.success(httpResponse.text);
    }, 
    function (error) {
        response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```

My guess is your request to `api-ilv.trulioo.com` runs into a problem, but since your code never calls `response.error` you see the *"success/error was not called"* error.

Comment: Well, this works in one sense. But, I'm still getting the code 141. Just now, it's returned in the `function (error)` `{"code":141,"error":"Error: undefined undefined"}`

Answer (score 0):

For single request http bridge you don't need .then functions :
You can use it more simply with success / error function :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function (request, response) { 
    var baseurl = "https://api-ilv.trulioo.com/v3/truDetect";  
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: baseurl,{
            'api_key':'1234567890',
            'provider_name':'fb',
            'provider_url':'https://www.facebook.com/testing'
        },
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse.text );
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });  
});
```